# How to show all tasks in reminder window - not just overdue tasks

Tags: tasks

Currently my pop up reminder window shows overdue tasks that I have set.  They are overdue because the date for completing the task has passed.  I would like to be able to also see my future tasks that have been set, not just the overdue tasks.  How do I show these in this window, or is there another place that it would show as a list?

Comment: You can set a reminder before the due date, or maybe you want an activity list view?